# DI with unit tests called from elsewhere in application?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

I am attempting to do something similar to the following:

```
import unittest

class foo:
    one = 1
    two = 1

class bar:
    one = 2
    two = 2


class my_test(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, di_source):
        self.di = di_source
        print 'initing my_test'

    def setUp(self):
        print 'setting up!'

    def tearDown(self):
        print 'tearing down :('

    def test_case_one(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.di.one,1)

    def test_case_two(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.di.two, 2)


di_one = foo()
di_two = bar()

# called from elsewhere in my application
test_one = my_test(di_one).run()
test_one = my_test(di_two).run()
```

My goal is to:

- Be able to call `run()` on a test suite
- Provide a DI container at runtime to that test suite
- Take advantage of the `setUp` and `tearDown` functionality provided by the unit test framework

However, it seems when I attempt to do this that the unittest framework doesn't like my constructor:

```
AttributeError: 'my_test' object has no attribute '_testMethodName'
```

Is there a better way to structure this example to avoid this problem?

Comment: Your example highlights how you're calling the TestCase with the wrong arguments. You call it with a method name, not a custom object.

Use my_test('test_case_one'), or call the base constructor with such arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using something like this:

This allows you to create shared resources for a single suite, pass the resource to all unittests, and then test the object with multiple methods.

```
'''Example using a shared resource in a unittest'''


import unittest


def callable_function():
    '''Generic callable_function, this should actually be connected to an object constructor or something else''

    return {'a': 3}


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    '''Custom unittest test case'''

    def __init__(self, resource, method_name):
        super(MyTest, self).__init__(method_name)

        self._resource = resource

    def test_getitem(self):
        '''Test getting item'''

        self.assertEquals(self._resource['a'], 3)

    def test_setitem(self):
        '''Test getting item'''

        self._resource['b'] = 2
        self.assertEquals(self._resource['b'], 2)

    def test_mutable(self):
        '''Test changes persist across tests'''

        self.assertEquals(self._resource['b'], 2)


def run_suite():
    '''Run complete unittest suite'''

    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    item = callable_function()

    suite.addTests([
        MyTest(item, 'test_getitem'),
        MyTest(item, 'test_setitem'),
        MyTest(item, 'test_mutable'),
    ])

    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_suite()
```

EDIT: If you need to discover methods on the fly, you can do the following:

```
import inspect

def get_tests(cls):
    return [k for k, v in cls.__dict__.items() if k.startswith('test') and inspect.ismethod(v)]

for name in get_tests(MyTest):
    suite.addTest(MyTest(resource, name))
```

The idea is simple: override the `__init__` method so it takes a resource and method name, bind the resource to the class, and initialize the `TestCase` as normal.

When you run the test, just use the bound resource.

Comment: This will work for me I think. I don't like having to do the copy/pasted method name but that's better than the alternative I think!